# XMLTextReader get children

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, xmltextreader

I new ti XML and I'm struggling with some basics.

I have a XMLTextReader that reads through a document:

```
<node guid="e7071d4d-21b0-48c0-b803-daf202998633" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="body__6557_0"/>

<node guid="3bc0240f-cdf4-4e09-94de-a52d7bc0c4be" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="body__6558_0"/>

<node guid="59dd7ce9-176c-4a45-a45d-b632b675b6c9" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="body__6581_0"/>

<node guid="66166789-3500-46ef-b43b-34919481ad37" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="body__6582_0"/>

<node guid="95882524-a9a6-4a50-a3bc-fe7c31ef2e47" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="Fixed_Support_OD_610_1__1_0"/>


<node tag="GroupNode" imageindex="3" text="Group">

<node guid="295e5a94-3732-4b3d-81f4-b04636eb71c3" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="a_11_1__9_0"/>

<node guid="f56472cc-dd46-44c8-997f-113cb959661d" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="a_12_1__9_0"/>

</node>

<node guid="2ebcd33a-f8e7-46ea-b637-2b7e3120a7da" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="Rod_Hanger_610_1_0"/>

<node guid="9221b254-fe4c-4c10-b6d2-da21a46eeb56" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="Rod_Hanger_610_2_0"/>

<node guid="38b0b0ef-0a62-4392-a607-ce1e708503a3" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="Single_variable_spring_hanger1_610_1_0"/>

<node guid="c41ab0c6-2f91-4595-b015-204675d8eaa4" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="Single_variable_spring_hanger1_610_2_0"/>

<node guid="1a01282c-c82f-4c63-afc4-35636972b499" tag="3DMesh" imageindex="1" text="Single_variable_spring_hanger1_610_3_0"/>
```

I get to the "GroupNode", then I need to save the GUID of the child elements.
To do that... I'm thinking of looping through them and getting the info i need.

I cant seem to get the amount of of children so I can do a forloop through them.

Please help.

Here I deserialize the file and create a tree structure(3D) from the XML.

```
  public void Deserialize(UserControl_Designer_Tree TreeView, string FileName)
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = null;
        try
        {                
            TreeView.Multiselect_Tree_View.BeginUpdate(); //Disabling re-drawing of treeview till all nodes are added.

            reader = new XmlTextReader(FileName);

            TreeNode parentNode = null;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == XmlNodeTag)
                    {
                        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
                        bool isEmptyElement = reader.IsEmptyElement;

                        newNode = Node_Create(reader, TreeView);
.........
```

The following snippet comes from the Node_Create() methos where I return the types of nodes.

```
if (nodeTag == "GroupNode")
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode myNode = doc.ReadNode(Reader);  //Get current group node

            List<string> meshGUIDs = new List<string>();
            int y = myNode.ChildNodes.Count; //The the amount of nodes in that group

            if (y > 0)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < y; a++)
                {

                    Reader.Read();
                    nodeGuid = Reader.GetAttribute(XmlNodeGuidAttribute);
                    meshGUIDs.Add(nodeGuid);
                }

                List<Basic_Mesh> meshes = new List<Basic_Mesh>(meshGUIDs.Count);

                foreach (string meshGuiD in meshGUIDs)
                {
                    Basic_Mesh mesh = Mesh_Guid_Search(Tree.Designer_3D._3DModels_List, meshGuiD);
                    meshes.Add(mesh);
                }

                Group_Data groupData = Tree.Designer_3D._3DGrouping.Create("Group", meshes); //Create a Basic_Group object in the clarity control.
                return new Group_Node(nodeText, new List<Mesh_Node>(), groupData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: At what state is your `Reader` when you are getting into this section of the code? What happens before this section with the `Reader`?

Comment: Is this the complete XML or just an extract of it? Are there going to be multiple "GroupNode" nodes in the document?

Comment: This is not the complete XML. There could be multiple "GroupNodes" with any number of "children".

Comment: Updated post with code before the previous section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
if (Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
break;

nodeGuid = Reader.GetAttribute(XmlNodeGuidAttribute);
meshGUIDs.Add(nodeGuid);
}
```

Don't know if this is the best way of doing it, but it works in my case.

Thank you.